# Get time zone from time zone offset or the Date in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I am having a Date variable **effectiveDt** in the format
**Tue Oct 23 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)**

I want to get the Zone id (eg. America/Dominica, US/Hawaii etc..) from the above date 
I tried effectiveDt.getTimezoneOffset() which gives only the offset value

Please suggest how to retrieve the zone id

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the question marked as duplicate, scroll down to the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Internalization Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions)
can be used for getting the user timezone.

```
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```